# What CSS/jQuery to use to avoid website cutting off for users with low screen resolution?

Tags: jquery, css

I want a gray border around the site for users with the screen landscape to handle it, but the content is the most important thing that must appear - especially for those who do not have a wide enough screen (the border should simply not show for them or be cut off or whatnot). My current CSS always uses 200px on the left and right. I tried switching it to a percentage but it still just uses that. If I switch to specifying width in the body and not content that doesn't fix it either.

Here is the code for my existing site: http://jsfiddle.net/syQgH/1/, the relevant CSS is shown below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #e1ddd9;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, SunSans-Regular, Sans-Serif;
  color: #564b47;
  margin: 20px 200px 20px 200px;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is the full page result: http://jsfiddle.net/syQgH/1/embedded/result/

Users with smaller screen widths will see it cut off on the x-axis and a scrollbar on the y-axis. I know about adding overflow-y to add a scroll bar on the x-axis, but ideally, I can have dynamic gray space around the site that is 140px where screen landscape allows but little or none where it doesn't. I presume I should use percentages for this rather than fixed pixel values, but this seems to have the same effect as I do not want it to take effect for users without enough screen landscape.

I am open to a JavaScript/jQuery solution.

Comment: Did you check the CSS3 calc() function already? You can use it like so: calc(75% - 100px); For example: http://robertnyman.com/css3/calc/calc.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could consider is using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) in order to make your site responsive to the user's viewport size.

For example, in your CSS you could have something like this:

```css
/* Place your base CSS styles */
    
@media (max-width: 800px)
{ 
   /* styles for devices with screen smaller than 800px */ 
}
    
@media (max-width: 600px) 
{ 
   /* styles for devices with screen smaller than 600px */ 
}
```

Unfortunately, this can be difficult to achieve with a table-based layout, which is what seems to be the case with your linked JSFiddle. Inline styles (e.g.: `<div style="..."></div>`) are also difficult to cascade over with media queries without using the `!important` directive (which is generally considered a bad practice).

If it's possible, I would consider rewriting your HTML as a div-based layout with CSS classes instead of `inline-styles`, and then implementing media queries to solve this.

Having said that, you could try something like this for an interim solution:

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) 
{
   #frmLogin table img 
   {
      display: none;
   }
   #frmLogin table td > div
   {
      width: 200px !important;
   }
   #frmLogin hr
   {
      width: 200px !important;
   }
}
```

Here's the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syQgH/2/

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but that doesn't really fix it. I think the CSS must be redone with jQuery to allow for dynamic sizing.

Comment: @Dan how so? I agree with this answer

Comment: The JS Fiffle is not producing the intended result. It just takes up 100% of the screen mostly for everyone, I still want a wide gray background for those who have the screen landscape to spare.

Comment: @Dan this what you want. The code example provided in the jsfiddle may be broken but it really is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Media queries are a good answer. Actually it is the answer given by the HTML5 standard.

It is broadly supported:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

There are lot of tools built around the media queries feature.

A couple of examples:

- I discovered this recently, which is an online editor for responsive
  design, quite impressive: http://froont.com/
- Twitter [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) also addresses this.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Try making your `body` the full width and `#content`, say, 80% wide. Then lose the 200px margins and simply center the 80%.

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/syQgH/5/

Relevant CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
#content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

The next step you'll have is losing all of the `px` widths and heights and replacing the widths with % based vales (just lose the height - browsers figure it out; maybe add `max-width` if needed).

Then, as others have noted, use `@media` queries to set ideal sizing for several browser widths (for example, perhaps make `#content`'s width 95% on `@media (max-width: 600px)`.

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML, you can use:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Which will force your page's "100%" to be the width of the device.

Comment: This is only on mobile devices.